# How to add a React App in root folder and another in sub folder?

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

I have a react app in the root folder of a domain, say www.abc.com. I also have another backend admin react app that I would like users to access using www.abc.com/admin.

Right now, every time I try to do /admin, the main React App's route picks up the /admin and redirects me to a 404 Not Found page. It is catching this:

Is there a way I can structure the apps such that it pulls the 2nd admin app from the /admin instead?

Will I have to do this using .htaccess file?

This is the .htaccess file of the root app (React boilerplate):

```
# Enable rewriting
  RewriteEngine On

 # If its not HTTPS
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

# Comment out the RewriteCond above, and uncomment the RewriteCond below if you're using a load balancer (e.g. CloudFlare) for SSL
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

# Redirect to the same URL with https://, ignoring all further rules if  
this one is in effect
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

# If we get to here, it means we are on https://

# If the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# and the directory with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 # and we are not opening the root already (otherwise we get a redirect loop)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/$

 #REDIRECT FOR ADMIN - JUST A TEST TO SEE IF THIS WORKS

 Redirect 301 /admin http://www.google.com

 # Rewrite all requests to the root
 # RewriteRule ^(.*) /
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `react` or with `react-router` this question has to do with the config of your Apache web-server

Comment: Anup, did you find an answer to this question?